# Unable to launch a Wizard Page

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt

I am very new to UI coding, I have to create multiple wizard pages and then try navigating from one page to another. I have written the below code which I have read on a blog. But I am unable to launch it.

```
    public class MyWizardPage extends WizardPage {
        public MyWizardPage() {
            super("My Wizard");
        }

        public void createControl(Composite parent) {
            // Create the parent control
            Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
            composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

            // Create some controls
            new Label(composite, SWT.LEFT).setText("Field #1:");
            Text field1 = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
            field1.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

            new Label(composite, SWT.LEFT).setText("Field #2:");
            Text field2 = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
            field2.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

            // Important!
            setControl(composite);
        }
    }
```

Please help me in launching/running the program.

---

Modifications:

```
public class MyWizardPage extends WizardPage {
        /******Newly added code****************/
        static Composite composite=null;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            IWizard mypage= new MyWizardPage();
            WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(composite, mypage);
            dialog.open();
        }

/******Newly added code****************/


        public MyWizardPage() {
            super("My Wizard");
        }

        public void createControl(Composite parent) {
            // Create the parent control
            composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
            composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

            // Create some controls
            new Label(composite, SWT.LEFT).setText("Field #1:");
            Text field1 = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
            field1.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

            new Label(composite, SWT.LEFT).setText("Field #2:");
            Text field2 = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
            field2.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

            // Important!
            setControl(composite);
        }


    }
```

I have modified the code as above:

But I get the following error:
     MyWizard Page is not of IWizard Type. I did this because to instantiate a WizardDialogue object it requires IWizard Type.I tried to implement IWizard interafce for MyWizardPageClass but it requires implementation for 18 methods. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by unable to launch it? Have you written a `Wizard` to contain this page? Do you want to run the wizard from 'File > New' or somewhere else?

Comment: Read a proper tutorial such as [this one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWizards/article.html)

Comment: Use `WizardDialog`

Comment: @greg-449: thank you for the links.I shall trey the example in the link and will get back to  you, If I need further assistance.

Comment: @Shashwat, The project requirement says, I need to use WizardPage.

Comment: WizardPage to add the page in Wizard and WizardDialog to open the Wizard

Comment: @Shashwat, I have tried implementing as you said. But sorry. I am unable to get it working. i have updated the question with the code changes. Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go though below code for wizard and it pages:
See TestWizard main method which opens the wizard

Page One :

```
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class PageOne extends WizardPage {
    private Text text1;
    private Composite container;

    public PageOne() {
        super("First Page");
        setTitle("First Page");
        setDescription("Fake Wizard: First page");
    }

    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        container.setLayout(layout);
        layout.numColumns = 2;
        Label label1 = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        label1.setText("Put a value here.");

        text1 = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
        text1.setText("");
        text1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (!text1.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    setPageComplete(true);
                }
            }    
        });
        GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        text1.setLayoutData(gd);
        setControl(container);
        setPageComplete(false);
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return text1.getText();
    }
}
```

Page Two :

```
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class PageTwo extends WizardPage {
    private Text text1;
    private Composite container;

    public PageTwo() {
        super("Second Page");
        setTitle("Second Page");
        setDescription("Fake Wizard: Second page");
    }

    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        container.setLayout(layout);
        layout.numColumns = 2;
        Label label1 = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        label1.setText("Put a value here.");

        text1 = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
        text1.setText("");
        text1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (!text1.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    setPageComplete(true);
                }
            }
        });
        GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        text1.setLayoutData(gd);
        setControl(container);
        setPageComplete(false);
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return text1.getText();
    }
}
```

Demo Wizard :

```
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard;

public class DemoWizard extends Wizard {
    protected PageOne one;
    protected PageTwo two;

    public DemoWizard() {
        super();
        setNeedsProgressMonitor(true);
    }

    @Override
    public String getWindowTitle() {
        return "Export My Data";
    }

    @Override
    public void addPages() {
        one = new PageOne();
        two = new PageTwo();
        addPage(one);
        addPage(two);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performFinish() {
        // Print the result to the console
        System.out.println(one.getText1());
        System.out.println(two.getText1());

        return true;
    }
}
```

Main test class :

```
import org.eclipse.jface.window.Window;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class TestWizard {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));

        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Open Wizard");

        button.addListener(SWT.Selection, event -> {
            WizardDialog wizardDialog = new WizardDialog(shell, new DemoWizard());
                if (wizardDialog.open() == Window.OK) {
                    System.out.println("Ok pressed");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Cancel pressed");
                }
        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shashwant. I got what I needed. It will help me in going ahead with my work.  I am looking at Vogella but I found that a bit difficult as a beginner. I am even looking into a book The definitive guide to SWT and JFace by Robbert Harris. I  have completed 7 chapters, but the creation of the wizard was giving me problems.  Could you please refer me some resource or tutorials which I can start with.

Comment: Vogella's tutorials are good, There are many books but it depends on which level you want. I like Eclipse: Building Commercial-Quality Plug-ins,
By Eric Clayberg, Dan Rube but it is targeting 3.x

Comment: Alright, I shall look into those and will buy it after going through few chapters. thanks for the references.